# My Android Device Monitor won't open after i updated the new android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-device-monitor

My device monitor was working just fine before the update, after the update, I can't open the program and it will show a [chunk of error](http://paste.ofcode.org/FsYwytcaUNwwD2qrLbQi74) in the log file at the monitor configuration folder and I tried many different ways to solve like running on the administrator mode, changing environment variable path but to no avail. I even tried re-installing it but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/FsYwytcaUNwwD2qrLbQi74 Here is the error codes

Comment: Your error say Java 9 and Eclipse. Neither of which are supported by the Android team. Are you surprised by these errors, then?

Comment: Besides that, DDMS is being phased out, starting in 3.0 https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html

Comment: Okay thanks for the help, I'm still new to android and java just started learning about 2 weeks ago. Don't really know how it works yet. Do you have any tutorials that I can read up on to improve my knowledge in Android and Java in general.

Comment: My recommendation is step far away from Android until you learn Java itself. Asking for external resources is off topic for StackOverflow. You can see [**tag:java**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)

Comment: My second recommendation would be to learn Kotlin instead if you really want to do only Android development.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I doing this for my internship. and I don't really have any proper training for this. My company knows that I don't have any prior knowledge and skills for this and yet they hire me. I didn't choose to work here but I was put here by my school. So I am kinda stuck with learning Android from scratch. I did learn a basic Java early on but I'm not skilled at it.